# Evaluation of sum of power series $\sum \frac{n}{n^2-1}x^n$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, power-series

Evaluation of sum of power series $\sum \frac{n}{n^2-1}x^n$ ?

I know $\sum_{n\geq0} nx^n = x/(1-x)^2$, how do I Include the $\frac{1}{n^2-1}$ ?

Comment: You should first get to know the radius of convergence of the power series you intend to compute.

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 0):

You have to exclude $n=1$ since you don't want $0$ in the denominator.

For $|x| < 1$,

$$ \sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{n}{n^2-1} x^n = - \frac{x^2+1}{2x} \ln(1-x) - \frac{1}{2} - \frac{x}{4} $$

You get this by first writing $n/(n^2-1)$ in partial fractions:
$$ \frac{n}{n^2-1} = \frac{1}{2(n+1)} + \frac{1}{2(n-1)}$$

EDIT: Then
$$ \eqalign{\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{x^n}{2(n+1)} &= \frac{1}{2x} \sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}\cr
&= \frac{1}{2x} \sum_{n=3}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n}\cr
&= \frac{1}{2x} \left(-\ln(1-x) - x - \frac{x^2}{2} \right)}$$
while
$$ \eqalign{\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{x^n}{2(n-1)} &= \frac{x}{2} \sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{x^{n-1}}{n-1}\cr
&= \frac{x}{2} \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n}\cr
&= -\frac{x}{2} \ln(1-x) }$$

Comment: I don't see how you went from partial fractions to what the final answer is?